# Jupyter - Additional Cell Types

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'd like to used Jupyter Notebooks as an interactive textbook AND notebook for students. When dealing with school-age children, asking them to type a font tag in - or even putting one in and expecting them to type between the tags - is unrealistic. But it would be great to be able to have a cell for them to type their notes in that are formatted differently to the normal markdown text. The simplest solution, to my mind, is to have a "notes" cell type but I can't see any way to add this. Is there another solution, or a way to do this?